# How to extend Selection to a whole word in EditText?

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, selection

So, I have an EditText view and my idea is on a, lets say for now, touch event to select and copy the touched word into clipboard memory. So far I can set Selection through offset, but it is only `""`, because `getSelectionStart() = getSelectionEnd() = offset`. How can I extend it until the next encountered whitespace or end/start of text.

How could I extend one such selection in the above described manner?

Code so far:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        float x = event.getX() + getScrollX();
        int offset = getOffset(event);
        if(offset != Integer.MIN_VALUE){
                setSelection(offset);
                String selectedText = getText().toString()
                            .substring(getSelectionStart(), getSelectionEnd());

                   //TODO: extend selection otherwise copies ""

                putInClipMemory(selectedText);
        }
    return true;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could use a break iterator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44602493/3681880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to calculate the index of the next space after your start selection index and use that (`endIndex` below in my example) instead of `getSelectionEnd()` when calling `substring` when you're setting your `selectedText`.

**For example**:

```
String substringFromStartSelection = getText().toString().substring (getSelectionStart());
int nextSpaceIndex = substringFromStartSelection.indexOf(" "); 
int selectionEnd = getSelectionStart() + nextSpaceIndex;
```

Comment: Won't work if the word ends with a period, or space, or quote, or .... Another approach is to use `BreakIterator.getWordInstance()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219292/how-does-breakiterator-work-in-android